# Trouble with makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to write a make file that:

1) Turns the files myftpserver.c and myftpclient.c into myftpserver.o and myftpclient.o by just typing the command 'make'.

2)I'm also adding a 'clean' target for cleaning up the directory (removing all temporary files, object files and executable files)

3)using gcc compiler.

My current version is not working:

```
CC=gcc

myftpserver: myftpserver.o
    $(CC) -o myftpserver.o

myftpclient: myftpclient.o
    $(CC) -o myftpclient.o

clean: ? // not sure what to put here
```

This is my first time making a makefile. I've tried several other combinations but none seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make has rules built-in for basic C files, so you don't need to tell it how to build `myftpserver.o` or `myftpclient.o`. This Makefile should work correctly, and properly includes `.PHONY` so the `clean` rule won't get disabled in the presence of a file named "clean"

```
CC:=gcc

.PHONY: clean all

all: myftpserver myftpclient

myftpserver: myftpserver.o
myftpclient: myftpclient.o

clean:
        rm -f *~ *.o myftpserver myftpclient
```

To test:

```
$ make --dry-run
gcc    -c -o myftpserver.o myftpserver.c
gcc   myftpserver.o   -o myftpserver
gcc    -c -o myftpclient.o myftpclient.c
gcc   myftpclient.o   -o myftpclient
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: YES! thank you so much. I've spent an hour trying to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

You want instructions for compiling your .o file, and the rm shell command to clean:

```
CC=gcc

myftpserver: myftpserver.o
    $(CC) -o myftpserver myftpserver.o

myftpclient: myftpclient.o
    $(CC) -o myftpclient myftpclient.o

myftpserver.o: myftpserver.c
    $(CC) myftpserver.c

myftpclient.o: myftpclient.c
    $(CC) myftpclient.c

clean: 
    rm -f *~ *# *.o myftpserver myftpclient
```

Comment: It only got an a.out to build

Comment: Fixed: had to add name of output file after -o